# Как правильно выводить в шаблон angular 2+ переменные, которые асинхронно присваиваются

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте, как правильно выводить асинхронные значения переменных в шаблон, что бы отображалось только после того как переменная присвоится, думаю что можно через *ngIf проверять, но правильно ли это если таких переменных много?

Comment: А можно подробней?
Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите выводить переменную на экран, только после того, как она изменилась? Или как?

Comment: есть такой как бы его назвать параметр `?` будет выглядеть так `<div> {{message?.content}}</div>` в данном случае пока нет данных, не будет никаких ошибок, выведется только после того как переменная присвоится.

Comment: @Artsiom,  а можно ссылку на описание данного параметра. Честно говоря первый раз слышу о таком.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths